# How to get response's authorization header?

Tags: dart

I post `formdata` to server's login path with the following code:

```
var data = {"username": username, 'password' : password};
HttpRequest.postFormData(Service.serverUrl + "/login", data).then((response) {
if (response.status == 200) {
    response.responseHeaders.forEach((key, value){
        print(key);
        print(value);
    });
}});`
```

The server response headers are:

> authorization:ShelfAuthJwtSession eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0Njk4NDEzNjQsImV4cCI6MTQ2OTg0MzE2NCwiaXNzIjoiY2xvdWRfc2NhbGVfc3lzdGVtIiwic3ViIjoiQ0xPVUQtU0MtVkVORE9SIiwiYXVkIjpbbnVsbF0sInNpZCI6IjJmNGUxOGMwLTRjMzAtMTFlNi1hMmExLWFmMjY5MDNiNTBjOCIsInRzZSI6MTQ2OTkyNzc2NH0.OoEuYlsItdwjciyZxDTcMi29JSUyZcrZ_2EApkTA12c
>   content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   date:Sat, 30 Jul 2016 01:16:04 GMT
>   server:dart:io with Shelf
>   transfer-encoding:chunked
>   x-content-type-options:nosniff
>   x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
>   x-xss-protection:1; mode=block`

But it only prints the `content-type` header— the other headers not included. Why is that?

Comment: Hi, Try the getAllResponseHeaders method
 https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.18.0/dart-html/HttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders.html

Comment: I have tried...the result is same....

Comment: ok, Looking at the response int the Dartium dev tool, network section, the headers appears there?

Comment: yes, there they are....

Answer (score 0):

There is a small helper package that i use for http requests. It contains a httpUtils class that can return a full response object that includes the headers. It also works fine with Flutter!

Github : https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils

Install:

```
dependencies:
  basic_utils: ^1.3.0
```

Usage :

```dart
Response response = await HttpUtils.postForFullResponse(Service.serverUrl + "/login", data);
String authData = response.headers["authorization"];
```

All other http methods that are included in this package :

```dart
Future<Map<Response> getForFullResponse(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getForJson(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> getForString(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<Response> postForFullResponse(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> postForJson(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> postForString(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Response> putForFullResponse(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> putForJson(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> putForString(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Response deleteForFullResponse(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> deleteForJson(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> deleteForString(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Map<String, dynamic> getQueryParameterFromUrl(String url);
String addQueryParameterToUrl(String url, Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters);
```